# Solving BVP with variable coefficient on MATLAB

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, matlab, boundary-value-problem

I have the second order boundary value problem

$$
y''=\frac{k}{2\sqrt{t}}\left[Py'-2yy'-y(P-y))\frac{1}{2t} \right],
$$
with boundary conditions I will specify later in the code.

Setting $y=y_1$ and $y_2=y'$, I can consequently write the above as the following first order differential equation

$$
y_2'=y''= \frac{k}{2\sqrt{t}}\left[Py'_2-2y_1y_2-y_1(P-y_1))\frac{1}{2t} \right]
$$

I am having issues implementing this on MATLAB due to the independent variable $t$. Thus far, I have written

```
% input parameters
P = 100000;
H0 = 18;
H1 = 3629;
t1 = 11;
k = (1/(P*sqrt(t1)))*log((H1*(P-H0))/(H0*(P-H1)));


% boundary values
ya(1) = 18;
yb(1) = 3629;

% differential equation function 
f=@(x,y,t)[y(2);k/(2*sqrt(t))*(P*y(2)-2*y(1)*y(2)-y(1)*(P-y(1))/(2*t))];
  

bc=@(ya,yb) [ya(1)-18;yb(1)-3629]; % boundary conditions

t= linspace (0,45,100); % create mesh

solinit = bvpinit(t, [1 0]); % initial guess of the solution

sol = bvp4c(f, bc, solinit); % run solver
```

Each time, I get an error, however, e.g., this time that there are not enough input arguments. How should I incorporate this independent variable into the solver? If $t$ were constant, it would be easy.

Comment: What exactly is `x`, where does it come from? It seems that your equation is formulated for $y(t)$, thus `f=@(t,y) ...`

Comment: @LutzLehmann The x should be the first part preceding the semi-colon, namely y(2).

Comment: No, I mean where can one find it in the mathematical formula? If you want to set $x=y'$, then you need to say so. But then $y$ in the definition of `f` is not a vector, there is no `y(1),y(2)`. Replacing $(y,y')$ with $(x,y)$ is even more misleading, better use $(y,v)$ if that is the case. // With $t$ starting at zero you also get a division-by-zero problem.

Comment: The right side can be written as derivative of $v=\frac{y(P-y)}{\sqrt{t}}$, then $y''=\frac{k}{2}v'\implies y'=\frac{k}{2}v+C$. This reduced equation could be slightly less singular at $t=0$.

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann Excellent catch. You should give it as a good partial answer !

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get a result and are not married to the idea of just using the equation in its original form, then you can first notice that $(y(P-y))'=(P-2y)y'$, so that all the terms with $y$ on the right side are contained in a factor of the form $2tf'(y)-f(y)$. An integrating factor for that is $\frac1{2t^{3/2}}$, so that with
$$
v=\frac{y(P-y)}{\sqrt{t}}
$$
the differential equation gets the compact form
$$
y''=\frac{k}{2}v'\implies y'=v+C=\frac{k}{2}\frac{y(P-y)}{\sqrt{t}}+C
$$
This now is a Riccati equation, thus one can set $y=\frac{2\sqrt{t}}{k}\frac{u'}{u}$ to get
$$
\frac{2\sqrt{t}}{k}\frac{u''}{u}-\frac{2\sqrt{t}}{k}\frac{u'^2}{u^2}+\frac{1}{k\sqrt{t}}\frac{u'}{u}=P\frac{u'}{u}-\frac{2\sqrt{t}}{k}\frac{u'^2}{u^2}+C
\\~\\
2tu''+(1-Pk\sqrt{t})u'-Ck\sqrt{t}u=0
$$
Apparently the singularity at $t=0$ still has bounded solutions that are power series in $\sqrt{t}$? Try $u(t)=f(\sqrt{t})$, or $f(s)=u(s^2)$, then $f'(s)=2su'(s^2)$, $f''(s)=4s^2u''(s^2)+2u'(s^2)=4tu''(t)+2u'(t)$ giving
$$
\frac12f''(s)-\frac{Pk}{2}f'(s)-Cksf(s)=0.
$$
This now is quite regular.

---

Let's finally translate the boundary conditions $y(0)=y_0$, $y(L)=y_L$.
The Riccati transformation is singular at $t=0$, meaning that $u'(0)=\pm\infty$, which can not be implemented in a direct manner.

---

Thus exchange the order of the tricks, set $g(s)=y(s^2)$ in the first-order equation
$$
g'(s)=2sy(s^2)=ky(P-y)+2sC=kg(P-g)+2sC
$$
This is now a quite regular Riccati equation with boundary conditions $$g(0)=y_0, ~~~ g(\sqrt{L})=y_L.$$

This can now be directly implemented. In Matlab the state space for this is $(g,C)$ with $C'=0$.

One could also proceed to the Riccati transformation into a linear DE which usually serves to postpone the occurrence of singularities from the solver to the post-processing. Here one would set $g(s)-\frac{P}{2}=\frac1{k}\frac{f'(s)}{f(s)}$ to get
$$
\frac{f''}{f}-\frac{f'^2}{f^2}=-\frac{f'^2}{f^2}+\frac{k^2P^2}{4}+2kCs
\\~\\
f''=\left(\frac{k^2P^2}{4}+2kCs\right)f
$$
with state components $(f,f',C)$, boundary conditions
$$
f(0)=1/k,~~~ f'(0)=y_0-P/2,~~~ f'(\sqrt{L})-k(y_L-P/2)f(\sqrt{L})=0.
$$

Comment: [+1] Very well written !